# Repeat Reanimated Animation without using Web APIs (setInterval)

Tags: react-native, expo, ui-thread, react-native-reanimated

So I have an animation using `React Native Reanimated` that repeats every 3 seconds and updates the `SharedValue`. I have implemented it as shown below using `setInterval`.

```js
const SomeThreshold = 5;

useEffect(() => {
  progress.value = 0;

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (progress.value === SomeThreshold) {
      progress.value = 0;
      return;
    }

    progress.value = withTiming(progress.value + 1, {
      duration: 2000,
    });
  }, 3000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

What I want to achieve is

-> Animation Starts

-> Progress = 1

-> Progress = 2

-> Progress = 3

-> Progress = 4

-> Progress = 5

-> Progress = 1

-> Progress = 2

and this goes on infinitely.

Is there any way to implement it without using Web APIs like setInterval and maybe using `withRepeat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of:

- [`withRepeat`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/animations/withRepeat/), a Reanimated function that repeats an animation a specified number of times or infinitely: in your case, using -1, infinitely.
- [`withSequence`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/animations/withSequence/), another Reanimated function that runs the provided animations in a sequence: in your case, from 1 to 5.

That would be (from [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252340/discussion-between-vonc-and-kartikey)):

```js
const SomeThreshold = 5;

const Example = () => {
  const progress = useSharedValue(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    progress.value = withRepeat(
      withSequence(
        withTiming(0), 
        ...Array(SomeThreshold)
          .fill(0)
          .map((_, i) => withTiming(i + 1, {duration: 2000 })),
      ),
      -1,
    );
  }, []);

// ...
};
```

The idea is to use `Array(SomeThreshold).fill(0).map((_, i) => withTiming(i + 1, {duration: 3000}))` to create an array of `withTiming` animations that will update the progress value from 1 to `SomeThreshold`, with each update taking 3 seconds.

The `.map((_, i) => withTiming(i + 1, {duration: 3000}))` part maps over the array and for each element creates a `withTiming` animation that updates the progress value to `i + 1`.

Combined with `withRepeat(withSequence(...), -1)`, that would repeat infinitely.

`withSequence` takes in 2 parameters:

- First: an animation.
- Second: an array (iterable) of animations.

Comment: Woah..The idea looks good. It's just that typescript is complaining that `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.` for the `withSequence` statement. Any solution for that?

Comment: @Kartikey Possibly using an array literal should help. See my edited answer.

Comment: The progress.value expects a number, but with this implementation, it will return a number[]. Typescript complain `Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: @Kartikey Good point. For testing, can you try instead using [`Animated.sequence(`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#sequence) instead of `withSequence([` (so no more array): By using `Animated.sequence()`, you would create a single animation that runs the animations in sequence, which can be assigned to `progress.value` without encountering a type mismatch error.

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet for that (`Animated.sequence()` version)  in the answer?

Comment: Hey @VonC, `Animated.sequence` comes from `react-native` and not `react-native-reanimated` and also `AnimatableValue` and `SharedValue` are different. This doesn't work. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252340/discussion-between-vonc-and-kartikey).